# What are some good choices for the "name" field in a remember me token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have read many references to the Charles Miller best practices for tokens referenced here
[definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication).  But I have not seen any real examples.

My question is what should be used for the user name field? 
I am thinking this should not be a real name, nor an email.
I was thinking of using the gravatar_id, or the user id number (1 .. n).
The gravatar_id seems like overkill, and the id number seems weak.
What are some better choices?

**Edit**
I guess I am under the assumption the token should look something like this

```
"#{user.name}:#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}"  -> "user12:0a5be29627332034d4dd8a"
```

but having that user12 in plain text seems wrong.
So I think I am missing something basic with the concept

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking for a recommendation on what the column name should be for the "remember me" functionality of a user login system?

Comment: no, not the column name but rather what should be used for the "name" part in a two part remember me token.  the referenced guide says to use as a token the username , a separator character, and a random number